# IOS 15 SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest recognises only first phrase from a file

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

IOS 15 Swift 5.
I want to fully transcribe recorded audio from a file

```
    func transcribeAudio(url: URL) {
          let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
          let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: url)
          request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true;
          request.taskHint = .dictation;
    
          recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { [unowned self] (result, error) in
              guard let result = result else {
                  print("There was an error: \(error!)")
                  return
              }
    
              if result.isFinal {
                  print(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
              }
          }
      }
```

Console output first phrase instead of full text

How can I rewrite a code to transcribe the whole audio file?
Thanks!

Comment: The recognizer object needs to be a property.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to

1. Put request and recognizer to class props
2. Exclude partial results
3. Print all results, not final one

```
func transcribeAudio(url: URL) {
      request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: url)
      request?.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true;
      request?.shouldReportPartialResults = false;
      recognizer?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition   = true;
      recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request!) { [unowned self] (result, error) in
          guard let result = result else {
              print("There was an error: \(error!)")
              return
          }

          RNEventEmitter.emitter.sendEvent(withName: "OnRecognition", body: result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
          print(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
      }
 }
```